# XHTML - What elements are allowed within the <a> element?

Tags: html, xhtml, hyperlink, tags

I know `span` `strong` and `em`. Are there any others?
I'm trying to filter a text which goes inside a link, and need to know what elements should I leave unfiltered?

Comment: I've modified your question to talk of "elements", not "tags".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

According to the [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-strict.dtd_a.content), lots of elements:

```
br | span | bdo | map
object | img | tt | i | b | big | small 
ins | del | script | input | select | textarea | label | button
em | strong | dfn | code | q |
               samp | kbd | var | cite | abbr | acronym | sub | sup
```

Comment: +1 for the first answer to refer to the DTD, the true authority on the matter.

Comment: The DTD isn't the true authority on the matter. There are rules that simply can't be expressed in a DTD (such as the rule that `<a><span><a /></span></a>` is invalid). Additionally, time has moved on and newer specifications have been released. Since HTML 5 (including the XML serialisation of it), all interactive descendants of `<a>` are banned.

Answer (score 3):

For HTML 4.01 Transitional, for instance, you can pick the [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/loosedtd.html) from w3c site. Then search the `<!ELEMENT A` in the document and navigate the *entities*, like `%inline;` to know the allowed nested elements.

- `#PCDATA` is allowed.
- Through `%inline;` and `%fontstyle;`: `TT | I | B | U | S | STRIKE | BIG | SMALL`
- Through `%inline;` and `%pharse;`: `EM | STRONG | DFN | CODE | SAMP | KBD | VAR | CITE | ABBR | ACRONYM`
- ...and so on

They will, in turn, have other nested elements.

You can repeat the operation for other HTML DTDs.

To know how DTDs nesting rules work, I suggest to read a [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/default.asp).

Answer (score 3):

It is worth to mention that ["block-level links"](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/) are valid in HTML5.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using XHTML transitional, then `font`, `b`, `i`, `sub`, `sup`....AFAIK just about any inline tag (except for another link) will fit.

Answer (score 1):

Other inline tags should be legal inside `<a>` like `<img>`, `<abbr>`, etc.  Here's alist of all the inline tags:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_tag#Inline_elements

Also, since `<a>` is a body tag, inline body tags only inside it, please.