# How to call JavaScript from header to body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

How can I call this into body from header, I've tried all the ways on the internet and it just simply doesn't work, am I missing something obvious? How would you go about this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/dw-minion/assets/css/jstick/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/dw-minion/assets/css/jstick/jquery.stickem.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  
        $('.container').stickem(); 
    });
</script>
```

I should probably add that I have multiple instances of this running as I am applying the JavaScript inside content.php on WordPress. Is that the problem?

Here is my content.php file contents:

```
<div class="title-wrapper">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#comments" title="<?php comments_number( 'No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments' ); ?>">
        <div class="commentnumber"><?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?></div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="stickem-container">
        <div class="thelinks stickem">
            <div class="sharelinks">
                <div class="sharepinterest">
                    <?php echo get_simple_local_avatar( $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ); ?>
                </div>
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&p[images][0]=http://www.otlcampaign.org/sites/default/files/journey-for-justice-mlk-memorial.jpg&p[title]=<?php the_title(); ?>&p[summary]=Click+to+enlarge">
                    <div class="sharefacebook"></div>
                </a>
                <a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php the_title(); ?>+<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                     <div class="sharetwitter"></div>
                </a>
                <div class="sharegoogle"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="post-wrapper">
            <div class="entry-content">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_content(); ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><a>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery as well before that piece of code ?

Comment: *"ive tried all the ways on the internet"* apparently not. what you have should work, assuming you're including jQuery and it's stored in the jQuery var, and .container exists and that .stickem() works, none of which we can confirm/deny given the code you have provided.

Comment: As a sidenote, you should be using the `enque_script` methods to add scripts and set dependencies in Wordpress, and not hardcode in script tags.

Comment: First, figure out *Why* it doesn't work. Is the code inside the ready event being triggered? is the `.container` element being found? If both are yes, then the problem is with the plugin. If both are no, then there's probably a javascript error in your console. If one is yes and the other is no, then figure out *Why* `.container` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: How does the element you are trying to select look like?

Comment: its just a div element inside content.php on wordpress

Comment: Have you got some errors on web console|firebug etc ?

Comment: i had it working when the script was not in the head but it meant the script was not loading before the page which somehow meant that the script only worked if you waited 5 seconds without scrolling down.

Comment: Include the html in your question. Stickem is quite picky when it comes to html classes/elements. (http://viget.com/inspire/jquery-stick-em)

Comment: When someone posts a javascript/jquery question and then posts PHP in it when it is unrelated it makes it harder to debug/guess - it is easier to try to debug with the rendered markup.

Comment: Please review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149876/xhtml-what-elements-are-allowed-within-the-a-element

Answer (score 2):

Scripts should be enqueued with [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) in `functions.php`, not directly in other theme template files. Also, looks like the theme has jQuery bundled and that's `doing_it_wrong()`™.

Any [Conditional Tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) can be used to filter the enqueue in different pages.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_so_18774457' ) );

function enqueue_so_18774457()
{
    if( is_single() )
    {
        wp_enqueue_script( 
            'stickem-js', 
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/jstick/jquery.stickem.js', 
            array( 'jquery' ) // This enqueues jQuery as a dependency
        );
    }
}
```

And for small scripts, like `$('.container').stickem();`, this can be used:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'footer_so_18774457' );

function footer_so_18774457()
{
    if( !is_single() )
        return;

    echo "
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  $('.container').stickem(); });
    </script>";
}
```