# Why does `<label>` inside `<a>` tag disable the cursor pointer

Tags: html

Look at the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/m8w7ockz/9/). I've nested different tags under the `<a>` tag and when I hover over them they all maintain the cursor in the pointer state except when the nested element is a `<label>`.

Why does this happen? Does `<label>` have a default hover state of `cursor: default` ?

Comment: You're not supposed to use `label` elements without inputs. And even less inside `a` elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does `<label>` have a default hover state of `cursor: default` ?

The hover pseudo-class is irrelevant. The `cursor` property is intrinsically linked to "when the pointer is pointing at it" … but other than that: **Yes**

[image: Screenshot of DOM inspector]

---

It is probably worth pointing out that **your HTML is invalid**. It is forbidden to place interactive elements (like `<label>`s) inside other interactive elements (like `<a>`s).

Comment: According to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149876/xhtml-what-elements-are-allowed-within-the-a-element) you are allowed to put `label`s inside `a`s. I don't prefer using it this way but it is valid.

Comment: @er-han — That refers to an obsolete specification.

Answer (score 2):

yes.  That's cleary stated here

http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_label.asp

From that page:

Most browsers will display the  element with the following default values:

Example
label {
    cursor: default;
}

And easy enough to verify in chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 2):

You are not suppose to have `label` inside an `a` tag. `cursor` is set by user agent stylesheet. If you inspect the DOM closely, you'll see

[image]

And hence, if you want to set `cursor: pointer;`, you need to specifically override the user agent declaration using\

```
a label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

OR

```
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

> Note: I do not recommend you to do so. Semantically it makes no sense
>   putting a `label` inside an `a` tag. `label` are usually used to
>   `focus` text fields in your `form`. They are kind of an action element
>   just like `a` tags are.

Comment: No you can have `label` inside an `a` tag. But not `div` tag

Comment: @er-han You can but I do not recommend doing so. P.S You can have a `div` tag inside `a`

Comment: label is allowed but div is not allowed in a, these are W3 standards not mine.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there are limitations of which elements you are allowed within the a element.

[XHTML - What elements are allowed within the <a> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149876/xhtml-what-elements-are-allowed-within-the-a-element)

Secondly, yes label element has default property:

```
cursor: default
```