# Saved html is not the same as it's output in the browser

Tags: php, wordpress, html, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm working on a custom Wordpress theme for my personal website. at the moment, I'm trying to display my recent blogposts on the home page. The HTML is very basic, and PHP just provides the data.

Here is the code directly from the file:

```
          <a id="test1" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
             <li class="post-thumbnail">
              <div class="home-post-text">
              <div class="display-image" style="background-image:url(<?=get_the_post_thumbnail_url();?>);"></div>

                <div class="home-post-title"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                  <div class="post-category-link">
                    <a id="test2" href="<?=get_category_link(get_the_category()[0]->term_id);?>">
                      <?php echo get_the_category()[0]->name;?>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </a>
```

But when I go to the webpage, it act's funny. Closer look at the source code from inspect element yields this code:

```
    <a id="test1" href="http://localhost/2018/12/10/test-oped/"></a>
    <li class="post-thumbnail">
      <a id="test1" href="http://localhost/2018/12/10/test-oped/"></a>
      <div class="home-post-text">
            <a id="test1" href="http://localhost/2018/12/10/test-oped/">
            <div class="display-image" style="background-image:url(http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/board-chalk-chalkboard-459793.jpg);"></div>
            </a><div class="home-post-title"><a id="test1" href="http://localhost/2018/12/10/test-oped/"><span>test oped</span>
              </a><div class="post-category-link"><a id="test1" href="http://localhost/2018/12/10/test-oped/">
                </a><a id="test2" href="http://localhost/category/papers/">
                  Papers                    
        </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
```

In the original source code, there are only two `<a>` tags, I gave them the id's `test1` and `test2` respectively. But in inspect element the `<a>` tags are multiple tags and several closing tags for the links.

I cannot wrap my head around why this is happening. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance for all the help.

**UPDATE**

If I remove this, the code works perfectly fine:

```
             <div class="post-category-link">
                <a id="test2" href="<?=get_category_link(get_the_category()[0]->term_id);?>">
                  <?php echo get_the_category()[0]->name;?>
                </a>
              </div>
```

I have narrowed the problem down to

```
<a id="test2" href="<?=get_category_link(get_the_category()[0]->term_id);?>">
  <?php echo get_the_category()[0]->name;?>
</a>
```

The PHP is not the problem, because if I replace the snipped above with a normal `<a href="#">testing</a>` the problem persists.

**Answer and Final Results**
So a `<div>` cannot go inside a `<a>`, and another `<a>` cannot be nested inside an `<a>`. I replaced the DIVs with SPANS. The CSS is all over the place, but in short, I gave specific spans `display:block` and others `display:inline`. Here is the final HTML structure that works.

```
<li class="post-thumbnail">
  <span class="display-upper">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <span class="display-image" style="background-image:url(<?=get_the_post_thumbnail_url();?>);"></span>
        <span class="home-post-title"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></span>
    </a>
  </span>
  <span class="post-thumbnail-cat">
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link(get_the_category()[0]->term_id);?>">
      <span><?php echo get_the_category()[0]->name;?></span>
    </a>
  </span>
</li>
```

Comment: The HTML is incorrect. You cannot have an DIV inside an A. That's the reason why your explorer are closing your A's.

Comment: And more - you cannot have `<a>` in `<a>`.

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto How would I go about getting the result I'm after without the DIVs inside the <a>? My objective is to create thumbnails that can be clicked on anywhere. This link shows what the final results will look like (roughly): https://pasteboard.co/HR8kaZ4.png

Comment: @u_mulder If I want my thumbnail (each inside an <li> tag) to be clickable anywhere (not just the text, but the background too) and have a separate link that goes to somewhere else, in this case the category the post is in, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can read on your code, you have an A, and then, a DIV. That's something not allowed by standards, and then, each navigator will do with this piece of code something different giving you unexpected results.

You need to change your code for doing the <a> when it's necessary. For example, if you want to have a box with a image inside them, and all the box clickable, use <span> for defining the box. The additional link you need to do it OUTSIDE the box, because you cannot have an <a> inside another one too.

If you need more information for allowed tags inside <a>, please check [XHTML - What elements are allowed within the  element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149876/xhtml-what-elements-are-allowed-within-the-a-element).